# RPC endpoint for production environments

Tags: private-blockchain, infura, alchemy, aws, quicknode

**Context**

For testing environments, I'm spinning up AWS instances with App-chain client nodes and using the AWS ALB to access the exposed RPC endpoint. It is protected by the security group rules, so that only IPs I allow can access it. However, for production environments, I see there are already many services like Alchemy/Infura/Quicknode/etc... which offer such services.

**Question**

Is there a best-practice for maintaining RPC endpoints during production?

- Manually maintaining AWS instances and the exposed RPC endpoint seems like an option (which I'm doing during testing). But this doesn't seem very manageable once the system starts scaling.
- Or commercial alternatives (PaaS, Cloud providers, etc...)

The primary concern here would be high availability, fault-tolerance, and auto-scaling/robustness during times of high network activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give you a Chainstack example (since I'm with Chainstack, full disclosure) — it does the load balancing for you automatically and the RPC nodes are very scalable. You can also implement a basic load balancer yourself if that interests you.

Have a read, we have a full explanation & a guide [Make your DApp more reliable with Chainstack](https://docs.chainstack.com/docs/make-your-dapp-more-reliable-with-chainstack).

But TLDR is just spin up a Global Elastic Node (by going with the Standard configuration) and it'll do all the scaling for you.

And don't forget to properly secure your stuff too (bonus): [How to store your Web3 DApp secrets: Guide to environment variables](https://docs.chainstack.com/docs/how-to-store-your-web3-dapp-secrets-guide-to-environment-variables#secure-front-end-usage-via-custom-proxy).